# Firebase to Wordpress

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, firebase

I'm new to WordPress and I've also been having fun experimenting with Angular/Firebase.

I'm looking to find a way to have an Angular app connect with the WP API in a way that goes further than just displaying posts.

Can someone direct me towards how to submit a form to Firebase and have it simultaneously create a new post and/or page in the WordPress backend? I've come across Zapier but, a) It doesn't seem to be flexible enough for what I want to do and b) It's not free and I'd rather figure it out on my own (with some help from you guys of course.)

I'm plenty fine with being able to use an $http request to list and display posts... but how can I create NEW posts?

PS: I don't NEED to use Firebase. Mainly, I'm really most concerned with creating a new post and/or comment without having to actually do it from the wp-admin.

Comment: hi did you find a solution to your answer. I am trying to achieve the same thing my my Ionic project